# ProcedureNotFound gds.list()

Tags: graph, plugins, neo4j

While working with Neo4j Desktop (version 4.4.5), I am unable to call any procedure from gds library though I have added the plugin already. Even on calling

```
CALL gds.list()
```

I am getting the below error message

```
Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureNotFound
There is no procedure with the name `gds.list` registered for this database instance. Please 
ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.
```

It looks like gds library is not visible even after installation.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `gds.list()` is not a procedure but rather a function. Try the following:

```
RETURN gds.list()
```